# Debian's libfuse-dev equivalent for Arch

Tags: fuse, arch

Debian has the *libfuse-dev* package:

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libfuse-dev

When I search for *fuse* in the Arch repo, none of the results seem to be the right one.

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=50&K=fuse&PP=50&SB=m&SO=a

Comment: @dratenik, Thank you! that was it. Please post it as an answer.  I ended up in that page by using google.

Answer (score 0):

I think the search you should have been doing is https://archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=fuse&maintainer=&flagged= where I can see fuse2 and fuse3. They are close to the debian `-dev` package in that they have the C headers and the libraries in them. The only thing missing compared to the debian package is the static version of the library, if you need that, you probably have to compile it from source.